# WooCommerce fulfillment api

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

I am making the order management system and try to integrate woocommerce api.
I read the document, found it quite different with the other ecommerce api.
When we need to pull order from the Woocommerce, use the /wp-json/wc/v3/orders api.
But when I done the order fulfillment and try to imform the shipment(advanced shipping notice), like send the tracking number correspones the order, which api should I use?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To update an existing order in WooCommerce you add the order id to the url like this `/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/<id>` and the request needs to be an `PUT`.

To store tracking url I would suggest you save it as a meta_field on the order. You can then easily access it in WooCommerce and display it where you want. Request can look like this:

```
{
  "meta_data": [
    {
      "key": "_tracking_number",
      "value": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can read more about it here https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#update-an-order